# How to show ajax response data into Laravel php variable inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a view where some data is shown in a table with filtering option. When I choose an option of search from the filtering part I want only table part will be refreshed and shown the updated data. It means recent table data should clear new filtered data should show in table.
I have successfully filtered data from database using Ajax. But can't show the filtered data (Ajax response) in the table.

Comment: My code is in first answer.Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')


{{--//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

<div class="">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 borrower_id">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <h2>Pending Loans</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 "  >
                        <h6>Branch</h6>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Branch Name" aria-label="Search" id="branch_selector" name="branch_selector" value="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
                        <h6>Center</h6>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Center Name" aria-label="Search" id="center_selector" name="center_selector" value="" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
                        <h6>Group</h6>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Group Number" aria-label="Search" id="group_selector" name="group_selector" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3" >
                         <h6>Search</h6>
                        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{-- @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
</div>
@endif --}}

<table class="table table-bordered" id="loan_table">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Borrower No</th>
        <th>Loan Stage</th>
        <th>Loan Amount</th>

        <th>Release Date</th>


        <th width="200px">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($loans as $loan)



    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $loan->borrower_no }}</td>
        <td>{{ $loan->loan_stage }}</td>
        <td>{{ $loan->loan_amount }}</td>

        <td>{{ $loan->release_date }}</td>

        <td width="100px">

            <form action="{{ route('approving.destroy',$loan->borrower_no) }}" method="POST">

                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('approving.show',$loan->borrower_no) }}">Details of Borrower</a>
                {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" >Show</button>--}}
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="/approving/test/{{$loan->borrower_no}}">Approve</a>

                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Reject</button>
            </form>
        </td>

    </tr>

    @endforeach
</table>

{!! $loans->links() !!}

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // var la = $(loans).val();

        $(branch_selector).click(function(){
            var branch = $(this).val();
            console.log(branch)


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{ ('/bseclector') }}',
                data: {'id':branch},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    data.forEach(function(item){
                        console.log(item);
                        // $('#loan_table').append('$loans'+item);
                   })




             }

                });
            });

        $(center_selector).click(function () {
            var center = $(this).val();
            console.log(center);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{ ('/cseclector') }}',
                data: {'id':center},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
        $(group_selector).click(function () {
            var group = $(this).val();
            console.log(group);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{{ ('/gseclector') }}',
                data: {'id':group},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    ;
                   data.forEach(function(item){
                        console.log(item);
                        // $('#loan_table').append('$loans'+item);
                        // $('#loan_table').append(${item+'$loans');
                        // $('#loan_table').append('<td>'+item.borrower_no+'</td>');
                        // $('#loan_table').append('<td>'+item.loan_stage+'</td>');

                   })
                // });
                }
            });

        });
        });


</script>



@endsection
@endsection
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: It's really not clear what the specific problem is and with no written explanation for this answer what it does to solve whatever the problem is. Far too much code here for a [mcve]. I would suggest getting a better feel for how this site works before trying to ask and answer your own question. It is very hard to see how this will be of much value to others in the future without fully understanding what the specific problem is in the first place or how this solves it

Comment: Yes,suddenly i did. dbf